# Flutter : Change state of a Widget from main() method

Tags: flutter

I am  trying to read data from [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) storage and after the reading is complete, I need to update the state of the class `_MyAppState`.
Accessing Hive is done in the main method since the initialized hive box is to be accessed in other classes as well.

The code I wrote is given below. What I need is to update the variable `_loading` of `_MyAppState` class from main() method after the reading is complete.

```
void main() async {
  var _dataReadFromHive = {};

  runApp(MyApp());


  final appDocDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.init(appDocDir.path);

  //read data from hive
  Hive.openBox('data').then((status){
   var box = Hive.box('data');
   //read data
   //after reading, update the state of MyAppState class

  });
}

...

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
    var _loading = true;

    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Material(
            child:Center(
                child : _loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text("Loaded"),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Please help me with this. I tried [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html), but I am missing something( I am a noob in flutter ).

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't update the state from main function.
Call your function from initState as shown in the code and update the state of the app from there.

I hope this helps.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _loading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    readDataFromHive();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: _loading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text("Loaded"),
      ),
    );
  }

  void readDataFromHive() async{
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    final appDocDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    await Hive.init(appDocDir.path);

    //read data from hive
    Hive.openBox('data').then((status) {
      var box = Hive.box('data');
      //read data
      //after reading, update the state of MyAppState class
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```